# Cannot convert string to decimal number - T-sql

Tags: t-sql

I used this function to extract decimal numbers from a string:

```
ALTER Function [dbo].[udf_ExtractNumber] (@String nvarchar(256))
RETURNS nvarchar(max)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @AlphaNumeric varchar(256)
,@Res varchar(256)

SET @AlphaNumeric = @String
SET @Res = NULL

WHILE (PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', @AlphaNumeric) > 0 )
BEGIN
    IF (PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', @AlphaNumeric) >0 AND PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', @AlphaNumeric) < CHARINDEX(',', @AlphaNumeric))
                BEGIN 
                    SET @Res = CONCAT(@Res ,SUBSTRING(@AlphaNumeric, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', @AlphaNumeric), 1) )
                    SET @AlphaNumeric = RIGHT(@AlphaNumeric,len(@AlphaNumeric)- PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', @AlphaNumeric))
                END
            ELSE IF (CHARINDEX(',', @AlphaNumeric) >0  AND CHARINDEX(',', @AlphaNumeric) < PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', @AlphaNumeric))
                BEGIN 
                    SET @Res = CONCAT(@Res ,SUBSTRING(@AlphaNumeric, CHARINDEX(',', @AlphaNumeric), 1) )
                    SET @AlphaNumeric = RIGHT(@AlphaNumeric,len(@AlphaNumeric)- CHARINDEX(',', @AlphaNumeric))
                END
            ELSE IF (PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', @AlphaNumeric) >0)
                BEGIN 
                    SET @Res = CONCAT(@Res, SUBSTRING(@AlphaNumeric, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', @AlphaNumeric), 1) )
                    SET @AlphaNumeric = RIGHT(@AlphaNumeric,len(@AlphaNumeric)- PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', @AlphaNumeric))
                END
            ELSE IF (CHARINDEX(',', @AlphaNumeric) >0 )
                BEGIN 
                    SET @Res = CONCAT(@Res,SUBSTRING(@AlphaNumeric, CHARINDEX(',', @AlphaNumeric), 1))
                    SET @AlphaNumeric = RIGHT(@AlphaNumeric,len(@AlphaNumeric)- CHARINDEX(',', @AlphaNumeric))
    END

END
Return @Res
```

This is working fine, output is exactly what i want.
It converts for example "adsfadf 18,12 adfasdsfa" to 18,12
However, when I want to work with the number I cannot convert it to a float.
Dividing or multiplying it gives the following error:

Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '7,5' to data type int.

Comment: if its the case just replace ',' to '.'

Comment: What are you expecting here exactly? `'7,5'` *isn't* an `int`, it 2 digits comma separated. What `int` would you expect `'7,5'` to be?

Comment: Side note, If you're providing a `nvarchar(256)` as the input parameter, why are you expecting a string that is up to **1 billion** characters to be returned?

Comment: When I use the function like this: ,replace(dbo.udf_ExtractNumber(dbo.FirstWord_v2(string)),',','.')*5  as example.
I get the following error:
Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '7.5' to data type int.

Comment: @larnu, fair point for nvarchar(max), i took this from another post..

Comment: *Somewhere* you are trying to convert the value `N'7,5'` to an `int`; that is the problem. The error is telling you the problem here. *We* can't run your code, so we don't know where are why this is happening.

Comment: In truth, I suspect you have severely overly complicated the issue; perhaps asking a different question, detailing what you are trying to achieve, with sample data and expected results, is in order.

Comment: Got it fixed, thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on comments of Ali Fidenli, I adjust the last part of the code to get it working. Thanks

```
END
Return replace(@Res,',','.')
```

Comment: I would be surprised if this works, `N'7.5'` isn't a valid `int` value either. `int` values don't have decimal places.

Comment: I think it has to do something with my system settings  decimal and komma